# Moose - imported functions don't count as role methods?

Tags: perl, roles, moose

I have a role that declares that it requires a method (with `requires`).
I'm trying to install the method by directly defining it in the class's symbol table.
However, in some cases it works and in others it doesn't.

In the following, WORKS means no errors are reported, DOESN'T WORK means I get the error: `'arole' requires the method 'finddepth' to be implemented by 'aclass'`

```
package arole;

use Moose::Role;

requires 'finddepth';

package anexporter;

sub import {
  no strict 'refs';
  *{ "aclass::finddepth" } = sub {};
}

package anexporter2;
sub import {
  eval "sub aclass::finddepth {}";
}

package aclass;

use Moose;

# WORKS:
# sub finddepth { }

# WORKS:
# BEGIN { *{finddepth} = sub {} };

# DOESN'T WORK:
# use File::Find qw(finddepth);

# DOESN'T WORK:
# BEGIN { anexporter->import };

# WORKS:
# BEGIN { no strict 'refs'; *{ "aclass::finddepth" } = sub { }};

# WORKS:
# BEGIN { anexporter2->import };

with 'arole';

1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that Moose tries very hard to track where methods are coming from so that anything not defined in the local package isn't accidentally treated as a method.

If instead of using the raw glob you were to use the Moose metaprotocol to inject the import this would work, because Moose would then know you were trying to explicitly add a method.

```
package anexporter {

    sub import {
        aclass->meta->add_method(finddepth => sub {})
    }

}
```

However this does mean that anything on CPAN (like File::Find's finddepth) would need to be wrapped. Which since typically exports aren't expecting to be called as methods, would probably need to happen anyway.

Comment: follow-up question: how can `Moose` tell the difference between `BEGIN { *{finddepth} = sub {} }` and `BEGIN { anexporter->import }`?

Comment: I'm not an expert on core, but my the first the coderef is defined/created in the current package the second is created in a foreign package and the local SV would have a flag saying it's a copy (I think). This is a question for rafl or doy in #moose.

Comment: @user5402, In `BEGIN { *{finddepth} = sub {} }`, the sub was compiled in the current package. In `BEGIN { anexporter->import }`, the sub wasn't compiled in the current package. You can see the difference by printing `__PACKAGE__` from the subs.

Comment: @ikegami - there's got to be more to it because the `anexporter2` example works and in that case `__PACKAGE__` is `anexporter2`, not `aclass`.

Answer (score 0):

Your role is looking for a method named finddepth; simply importing it from some other package does not a method make. I'd wrap it in a method, as your role methods would need to call finddepth as a method anyways, to have everything resolve properly.

```
# in package aclass
use File::Find;

sub finddepth { shift; File::Find::finddepth(@_) }
```

This has a couple advbantages: it's not surprising, it's not magical, and everything works as expected.